# Python pytest mock socket.recv issue

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, pytest

I have a simple Python class as follows (simplified example) in a file `example.py`

```
import socket

class MySocket(object):

    _connection = None

    def ConnectAndGetData(self, ip, port):

        self._connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._connection.settimeout(10)
        self._connection.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
        self._connection.connect(ip, port)
        data = 0
        return(data)
```

In another file (`test_example.py`) I have the unit test as follows:

```
from example import MySocket
import mock

class TestExample(object):

    @mock.patch('example.socket.socket.connect')
    def test_connect(self, mock_connect):
        IP = '10.10.10.10'
        port = '5000'
        my_socket = MySocket()
        data = my_socket.ConnectAndGetData(IP, port)
        mock_connect.assert_called_with(IP, port)
```

This works fine (`connect` got mocked). However, now I add the `recv` method to `example.py`

```
import socket

class MySocket(object):

    _connection = None

    def ConnectAndGetData(self, ip, port):

        self._connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._connection.settimeout(10)
        self._connection.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
        self._connection.connect(ip, port)
        data = self._connection.recv(5)
        return(data)
```

and appropriate test code to `test_example.py`

```
from example import MySocket
import mock

class TestExample(object):

    @mock.patch('example.socket.socket.recv')
    @mock.patch('example.socket.socket.connect')
    def test_connect(self, mock_connect, mock_recv):
        IP = '10.10.10.10'
        port = '5000'
        mock_recv.side_effect = ["he", "llo"]
        my_socket = MySocket()
        data = my_socket.ConnectAndGetData(IP, port)
        mock_connect.assert_called_with(IP, port)
        assert data == "hello"
```

Now this fails with the following message ...

```
F
self = <test_example.TestExample object at 0x032836F0>
mock_connect = <MagicMock name='connect' id='52967856'>
mock_recv = <MagicMock name='recv' id='45677456'>

    @mock.patch('example.socket.socket.recv')
    @mock.patch('example.socket.socket.connect')
    def test_connect(self, mock_connect, mock_recv):
            IP = '10.10.10.10'
            port = '5000'
            mock_recv.side_effect = ["he", "llo"]
            my_socket = MySocket()
>           data = my_socket.ConnectAndGetData(IP, port)

examples\test_example.py:14: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
examples\example.py:9: in ConnectAndGetData
    self._connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # type: socket
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <socket._socketobject object at 0x033EF6C0>, family = 2, type = 1
proto = 0, _sock = <socket object, fd=508, family=2, type=1, protocol=0>

    def __init__(self, family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, _sock=None):
        if _sock is None:
            _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
        self._sock = _sock
        for method in _delegate_methods:
>           setattr(self, method, getattr(_sock, method))
E           AttributeError: '_socketobject' object attribute 'recv' is read-only

..\..\Python27Dev\lib\socket.py:194: AttributeError
```

Can someone shed light on this error (`AttributeError: '_socketobject' object attribute 'recv' is read-only`) above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues testing with sockets, but worked round them with mockito. I've included snippets below - HTH:

```
>>> from mockito import when, unstub
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> import socket
>>> mock_socket = Mock(spec=socket.socket)
>>> attrs = { 'recv.return_value': u'this is the string returned' }
>>> mock_socket.configure_mock(**attrs)
>>> mock_socket.recv(1024)
u'this is the string returned'
>>> when(socket).socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).thenReturn(mock_socket)
<mockito.invocation.AnswerSelector object at 0x7fd102fd5890>
>>> from myapps.app1 import mysocket
>>> rc = mysocket.RestClient()
>>> rc.some_route()
"u'this is the string returned'"
>>> mock_socket.mock_calls
[call.recv(1024),
 call.connect(('daring.cwi.nl', 50007)),
 call.sendall('Hello, world'),
 call.recv(1024),
 call.close()]
```

And the mysocket.py file:

```
# Echo client program
import socket

HOST = 'daring.cwi.nl'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server

class RestClient():
    def some_route(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        s.sendall('Hello, world')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        s.close()
        return repr(data)
```